# How to store and display uploaded image in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to JS and HTML, and this is a very simple question, but I haven't found any straightforward solution. What I'm trying to do is in the form submission, there is a file upload. When the form is submitted, I want to store the uploaded image in an object under the "Recipe name", I can do all that, what I need help in is figuring out how to store uploaded images and then redisplay them as an image all on the html page.

In this code, I set image to the getelementbyid "imageupload" and just to test it out, when the button is pushed, it would set the background image to the url. I know just setting it equal to image shouldn't be the URL, but I've tried image.value and image.src and a couple others, and none of them worked, so I just need to know how to get something like this to work.

```
const possibleIngredients = [];
const log = document.getElementById("log");
possibleIngredients.length = 0;
let uniqueIngredients = [];
const recipes = {};
const recipeAdder = document.getElementById('RecipeAdder');
const recipeName = document.getElementById('inputrecipetitle');
const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchbutton');
const threshold = 3
const compareButton = document.getElementById('submitknowningredients');


function addRecipe(title, input){ 
   const ingredients = Array.from(input).map(input => input.value);
   recipes[title] = ingredients;
}
//below is the levenshtein function, basically just allowing error in between search and title
function levenshtein(a, b) {
    const matrix = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
      matrix[i] = [i];
    }
  
    for (let j = 0; j <= a.length; j++) {
      matrix[0][j] = j;
    }
  
    for (let i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
        if (b.charAt(i - 1) === a.charAt(j - 1)) {
          matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1];
        } else {
          matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1, matrix[i][j - 1] + 1, matrix[i - 1][j] + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  
    return matrix[b.length][a.length];
  }



recipeAdder.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   const input = document.querySelectorAll('.ingredients');
   const inputArray = Array.from(input);
   const recipeLink = document.getElementById('recipelinksubmit');
   const image = document.getElementById('imageupload');
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
   console.log(image);
   addRecipe(recipeName.value, inputArray);
    input.forEach(function(input){
    possibleIngredients.push(input.value);
    input.value = '';
    
});
 uniqueIngredients = [...new Set(possibleIngredients)];
});

searchButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const recipeSearch = document.getElementById('recipesearch');
    for (const title in recipes){
        const normalizedSearch = recipeSearch.value.toLowerCase();
    const normalizedTitle = title.toLowerCase();
        const distance = levenshtein(normalizedSearch, normalizedTitle);
        if(distance <= threshold){
            console.log(recipes[title]);
        }
    }
})

compareButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const ingredientsInput =  document.getElementById('myingredients');
    const myIngredients = ingredientsInput.value.split(',').map(ingredient => ingredient.trim().toLowerCase());
    for(const title in recipes){
        const recipeIngredients = recipes[title].map(ingredient => ingredient.toLowerCase());
        const isMatch = recipeIngredients.every(ingredient => myIngredients.includes(ingredient));

        if(isMatch){
            console.log(`you can make ${title} with your ingredients`);
        }
    }


})


log.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(uniqueIngredients);
    for(const title in recipes){
        console.log(title, recipes[title]);
    }
    
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="recipefinder.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Recipe Finder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="scroll">Possible Recipes</h1>
    <h2 class="hadingredients">Ingredients In Stock:</h2>
    <div  class="possiblerecipes">
       
        <img src="img/brocolli_cheese.jpg" class = "pic1">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/GarlicBread.jpg" class="pic2">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/MangoCandy.jpg" class="pic3">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/Meatballs.jpg" class = "pic4">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/brocolli_cheese.jpg" class = "pic5">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/GarlicBread.jpg" class="pic6">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/MangoCandy.jpg" class="pic7">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/Meatballs.jpg" class = "pic8">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/brocolli_cheese.jpg" class = "pic9">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/GarlicBread.jpg" class="pic10">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/MangoCandy.jpg" class="pic11">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/Meatballs.jpg" class = "pic12">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/brocolli_cheese.jpg" class = "pic13">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/GarlicBread.jpg" class="pic14">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/MangoCandy.jpg" class="pic15">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>
        <img src="img/Meatballs.jpg" class = "pic16">
        <a class="init" href="https://google.com">Placeholder</a>

    </div>
    <div class="hadingredientslist">
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">✔️test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">❌test</p>
        <p class="hadingredient">❌test</p>





    </div>


    <form id="RecipeAdder">
        <label for="Enter your Recipe Name Here: ">Enter Your Recipe Name Here: </label>
        <input type="text" id="inputrecipetitle"><br>
        <label for="Enter Your Ingredients Below:">Enter Your Ingredients Below: </label><br>

        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace1" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace2" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace3" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace4" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace5" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace6" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace7" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace8" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace9" class="ingredients"><br>
        <input type="text" id="ingredientspace10" class="ingredients"><br>
        <label for="link" >Enter The Recipe Link Here: </label>
        <input type="text" id="recipelinksubmit" class="link"><br>
        <input type="file" id="imageupload" class="file">
        <button type="submit">Submit Recipe!</button>
        
    </form>
    <input type="text" id="recipesearch">
    <button id="searchbutton">Search Me</button>
<br>
    <input type="text" id="myingredients" placeholder="Enter Known Ingredients Here Seperated by a Comma"><br>
    <button id="submitknowningredients">Look for Recipes!</button>
    
    <button id="log">Log Me!</button>
    <script src="recipefinder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well if you want to upload images and store them on your server, you will need to figure out what server side language you are going to use to handle it. That is something you would need to investigate with your server's hosting plan.

Comment: As of now I'm not hosting it on any server, just my computer and vscode and test server on Chrome. How would it work if I'm hosting it on server or just on my computer?

Comment: If you want to move the image from one spot on your server and have it stored somewhere else you will need something "server side". Javascript,HTML and CSS are all client side. I would probably look into something like XAMPP

Comment: shouldn't I be able to store it client-side though? Like each time an image is submitted it is stored in the code, or is that not possible

Comment: But if you refresh the page, those images will no longer be stored. You would have to find some sort of persistent storage like sessionStorage or localStorage

Comment: ah, okay, I'll look into it then

Comment: Using HTML & Javascript  you can `browse` for a file anywhere on your computer & network(possibly) but Javascript does not have access to the computer's Filesystem - meaning it will **not** know the actual filepath of the file so you would **not** be able to reference that filepath later. You could possibly use a `canvas` object and write the image to the canvas and store the base64 representation of that file - perhaps in localStorage

Comment: FYI: You are not using the `label` elements correctly above. A `label` **must** be related to an `input` element of some sort in one of two ways. Either use the `for` attribute in the label - that `for` attribute should reference the ID of the input element. Alternatively the `input` element must be wholly within the `label` itself

Comment: localStorage is limited in size to, I think, something like 5Mb - so perhaps storing base64 data as I suggested might not be sensible if there are to be many images stored for a long period. If that is the case perhaps `indexedDB` might be more appropriate - though more complicated to use

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;` makes no sense - in this instance the variable `image` is simply a reference to the file input element rather than an actual image src

Comment: Yeah I didn't know whether the input would relay the file source or path and that would work. I know you need to do things like .value to return the text value, so I thought it would be something like that

Comment: In your code above you use a volatile storage mechanism, the `recipes` object literal. Any ingredients you add &/or images are stored ( or to be stored ) in that Object. This is fine but has no persistence across page loads - is that the intended means of operation or do you intend to be able to store this data (hopefully with image ) longer term and be usable after page reloads?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in setting the background image of a container element ( in this case the document.body ) as seems the case given the wording of the above you might find the following short snippet of use.

You bind an event listener to the `file` input field and process any changes made to the selection of files. The event handler has access to the `files` property - see [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) for information about the `File` api and [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications) about using this in applications.
With a reference to the file the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) api can be used to, funnily enough, read the file.

Upon successfully reading a file the FileReader instance will fire a `load` event which triggers a callback function that is used to create a new `Image` which in turn is then used as the `backgroundImage` property for the chosen container.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change',e=>{
  let file=e.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload=function( evt ){
        let img=new Image();
            img.onload=( e )=>{
              document.body.style.backgroundImage=`url(${img.src})`;
              
              /* 
              To obtain a "storable" string representation of the image
              - write the image to a canvas and use `toDataURL` to get
              the base64 encoded source data....
              */
              let canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
                  canvas.width=img.width;
                  canvas.height=img.height;
                  
              let ctxt=canvas.getContext('2d');
                  ctxt.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
              
              let imgstr=canvas.toDataURL( file.type );
              ctxt.clearRect(0,0,ctxt.canvas.width,ctxt.canvas.height);
              
              console.log( imgstr )
            }
        img.src = evt.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL( file );
});
```

```css
canvas{display:none}
```

```html
<input type='file' />
<canvas></canvas>
```

Browse for a image file on your local system to set as the background image.